# Equations written on LaTeX on a R Markdown document can't be referenced nor are they automatically numbered

Tags: latex, rstudio, r-markdown, bookdown

I just became a LaTeX user a couple days ago, so please bear with me if I don't succeed in explaining in an appropriate manner the problem that I'm facing.

I am writing an academic article that has embedded R code chunks on it. My intention is to load it up on my GitHub account. The text editor that I'm using is RStudio.

RStudio relies on the document format R Markdown, which has a distinctive feature that was intended —not a bug—: it is *simple*. When I say that it's simple I'm just quoting Yihui Xie. I actually don't understand what he means by that. **What I do know is that, unlike other text editors that support LaTeX, when I write an equation inside the equation environment like this**

> \begin{equation}
>
> a + b = c
>
> \end{equation}

**the HTML preview doesn't automatically assign a number to the equation.**

By the way, before you ask, on the preamble I have set the output as html_notebook.

Other problem that I have is that, if I assign a label to an equation like this

> \begin{equation}
>
> \label{eq:1} a + b = c
>
> \end{equation}

and in some other part of the document I intend to write a reference to that equation like this

> Recall \eqref{eq:1}

I get the following on the preview:

> Recall (???)

Although if I click on the (???) sign it does take me back to the equation.

Anyhow, on [this link](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/a-single-document.html) Yihui Xie offers a solution to all of this. **As far as I understood, the solution basically is to write the following on the preamble:**

> output:
>
> bookdown::html_document2: default

**but unfortunately this is not working for me.** If I click on the Knit button, the output I get is still not automatically numbered and the references are still (???) signs. How can I solve this?

Comment: See the syntax for cross-referencing equations here: https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-extensions-by-bookdown.html

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre]?